# sql stored procedure in visual studio 2008

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures, insert

I want to write stored procedure in visual studio that as a parameter recieves the name of project and runs in database TT and copies data from TT.dbo.LCTemp (where the LC is the name of the project recieved as a parameter) table to "TT.dbo.Points" table. both tables have 3 columns:
PT_ID, Projectname and DateCreated

I think I have written it wrong, here it is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.FromTmpToRegular
    @project varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN 
    declare @ptID varchar(20)
    declare @table varchar(20)

    set @table = 'TT.dbo.' + @project + 'Temp'
    set @ptID = @table + '.PT_ID'

    Insert into TT.dbo.Points Select * from [@table] where [@ptID] Not in(Select PT_ID from TT.dbo.Points)
END
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
EXEC ('Insert into TT.dbo.Points Select * from ' + @table + ' where ' + @ptID ' Not in(Select PT_ID from TT.dbo.Points)');
```

Or use parameters like this

```
Declare @SQL nVarChar(1000) --N.B. string must be unicode for sp_executesql
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM pubs.DBO.Authors WHERE au_lname = @AuthorName'

Exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@AuthorName nVarChar(50)', @AuthorName = 'white'
```